# How is $\sin \frac{|\varphi_n-\varphi|}{2}\leq \frac{|z_n-z|}{2|z|}$ where $z_n,z \in \mathbb C$ and $\varphi_n,\varphi =\arg z_n, \arg z$ resp

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, geometry

How is $\sin \frac{|\varphi_n-\varphi|}{2}\leq \frac{|z_n-z|}{2|z|}$ where $z_n,z \in \mathbb C$ and $\varphi_n,\varphi =\arg z_n, \arg z$ respectively.

There is a picture drawn here that I will attach if need be but it is unclear to me.

Comment: I think this inequality is fairly obvious if one draws a proper diagram. Think of two rays and a third ray bisecting the angle between the first two. Now you can choose $z$ and $z_n$ on the original two rays, one on each. Then $\sin\frac{|\phi_n - \phi|}{2}$ is equal to $\frac{|z_n - z|}{2|z|}$ if $z_n$ and $z$ have the same modulus. In all other cases , it would be lesser as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One knows that
$$
\sin \frac{|φ_n-φ|}{2}
=\frac12·\left|\frac{z_n}{|z_n|}-\frac{z}{|z|}\right|
=\frac1{2|z|}·\left|\frac{|z|}{|z_n|}z_n-z\right|
$$
Now you get to argue why the last factor can be bounded by $|z-z_n|$.